# Sequalize returns fulfilled promise with correct data, yet not as a desired JSON-object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, es6-promise

Backend:

```
exports.getSchedule = async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Fetching schedule...")
    console.log("user.id: ", req.body.user.id, " req.body.id (schedule id: ", req.body.id)

    const schedule = await Schedule.findOne({
        where: {
            ownerId: req.body.user.id,
            id: req.body.id
        },
    }).then(schedule => {

        console.log("test2: ", schedule.toJSON());
        res.status(200).send({
            schedule: schedule,
        });
    }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
        });
};
```

Frontend console:

```
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Promise
[[PromiseState]]
: 
"fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]
: 
Object
schedule
: 
{id: 18, name: 'wdwwddw', ownerId: '1', startDate: '2022-11-01', endDate: '2022-11-01', …}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

This is the code on the frontend that calls the request:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    console.log("props.id", props.id)
    if (props.id) {
      let schedule = Promise.resolve(AuthService.getSchedule(props.id));
      console.log("getschedule: ", schedule)
    }
/*    this.setState({
      id: props.id,
    })*/
  }
```

auth.service.js (also frontend):

```
  getSchedule(id) {
    let user = this.getCurrentUser()
    return axios
        .post(API_URL + "get-schedule", {
          user,
          id
        })
        .then(response => {
          if (response.data.accessToken) {
            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
          }
          return response.data;
        });
  }
```

I can see that the data in the returned promise is correct, but why is it still a promise? I thought I solved that with .then().

I really appreciate any help!

EDIT: My solution is below!

in `componentWillReceiveProps` i did this:

```
let schedule = await AuthService.getSchedule(props.id);
```

which solved the issue!

Comment: What do your frontend logs look like?

Comment: What do you mean? That's what I show under "Frontend console" in my main post. :) Everythign else looks good.

Comment: I mean the code to log those logs :p

Comment: Oh! I updated my answer with that.

Comment: "*why is it still a promise? I thought I solved that with .then().*" - no, `.then()` still returns a promise. You can "solve" this with `await`, but you will never get an immediate synchronous response and you cannot busy-wait (blocking) for it either.

Comment: I've tried using await but cant seem to get it to work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Nvm I finally made it work. Thanks for the reminder! Ill update my post with my solution as the question is locked.